# What's the difference between assigning a relationship in a database and just storing the primary key of the database as foreign key?

Tags: sql, database

This might be a bit of a novice database question but I've always had this doubt.

Why do we assign a relationship provided by Django or node datbase wrappers, that allows to connect to database models in a many to one, or one to one relationship. Why can't we just store, say the primary key of the Database A in Database B, thus ensuring Database A has a one to one relationship with Database B?

What is the need of doing this DatabaseA.hasOne(Database B), which ends up achieving the same thing, creates a databaseAId column in Database B and stores Database A's primary key ids there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are basically the same.
The reason for the wrapper is to consistently provide an interface that works in the language of choice.  For example I use ruby on rails and the same paradigm exists.  The wrappers allow you to write queries in the language you are using.

This practice also allow you define different relationships, for example has_many vs. has_one, where both would have a foreign key in the other table but only by using the above relationship will you know whether it's intended to be a has_many or has_one relationship.

Comment: One of the reasons that I came up with is, this makes the relationships more readable. Also, when defining many_to_many relationships, it helps you to have control over the name of this new relationship and again, helps in the readability. But apart from that, I see no advantage.

Comment: good usable names and labels are not just for readability, they are a very important part of good coding and making sustainable and maintainable applications.  You should spend time making good names and labels.  In 6 months your successor (or the future you) will be most grateful.  Good names and labels beat out most comments any day.

Answer (score 0):

Some terms of the description seems vague to me (what is Django ? Is the word database misused ?)

But usually creating a relationship in a database also usually ensures that the data you will enter in the foreign key column will be consitent. (For example you can not insert a foreign key if the record doesn't exist in foreign table.)

Comment: Yes.  However the question is why define the relationship somewhere when the foreign key itself defines that relationship.

Comment: Exactly! By django or node, I meant they allow nice wrappers/models, to write such relationships. But what can be the point of this?